# How to edit Rows in an Abstract Table Model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello i have this Abstract Table which im making a video hiring application with. I want the user to be able to sort through the table with buttons I have supplied. In the buttons I have a "Show only overDue videos" so when the user hits this button in my action listener i want to be able to hide the rows not delete them so when the user clicks another button they will re-appear any ideas on how i would go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `filtering` support provided by `JTable`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information and examples.

Comment: i tried it n and it didnt work i must be doing it wrong ill have another go

Comment: @Ross, did you download and try the demo code? Yes you are doing something wrong if it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah i tried it but it doesnt show me it sorting the row the only download it provides is showing me how the table is made values in table and a few check boxes i cant view the second part where they actually sort it so its kinda useless

Comment: The you did not download the proper demo. There is a working demo that shows exactly how filtering works.

Answer (score -2):

1) Maintain a master Data list. Intially the table model data will reflect the Master data.

2) When the user "press show only over due vidoes", iterate the master data and filter only the required elements and clear the table model and add only the filtered data to the table model and fire table model changed.

Comment: it sounds exactly what i want to do but how would i go about iterating through the master data, i get what your saying would i use a for loop to loop through the arraylist of master data then check if any of the hires are overdue then what would i do to only show my filtered data and how do i "fire table model changed"?

Comment: http://nealbuerger.com/2012/01/java-gui-using-abstracttablemodel/ here you have how to add and remove data from table model. In your case just set the filtered data and call firetablemodelchanged()

Comment: hey im just doing a bit of reading on  firetablemodelchanged() but there is not examples of how to use it, would u be able tp demonstrate how i would use it please would i use it in the action listener of the button or would i remove all the rows i dont need then call it?

Comment: -1, for suggestion a solution that is already supported in the base API. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. `it sounds exactly what i want to do` - why do you want to reinvent the wheel? This is exactly what the filtering support of JTable does, except JTable does all the work.