# How to remove a row from an Abstract Table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying this code in a button when its pressed it will remove a row but I get an error when it attempts to remove the row. Any ideas?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int searchedId = 1001;//ID of the product to remove from the table
            int row = -1;//index of row or -1 if not found

            //search for the row based on the ID in the first column
            for(int i=0;i<HireTable.getRowCount();++i)
                if(HireTable.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(searchedId)){
                    row = i;
                    break;
                }

            if(row != -1){
                HireTable.remove(row);//remove row
                System.out.println("yes");
            }else{
                //not found
                System.out.println("no");

             hireStats.fireTableDataChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

### Stack trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1195)
    at DataManager$2.actionPerformed(DataManager.java:155)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: If you're table model is based off `AbstractTableModel`, you'll need to post it

Comment: Based on your exception, you're trying to remove the nth component from the `JTable`, `at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1195)`.  `JTable#remove` doesn't effect the `TableModel`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Using JTable filtering is the proper way to solve this problem as has already been suggested in your other posting (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24215159/131872). Why is that you post code trying to reinvent the wheel instead of posting code showing how you tried to implement the filter? Spend you time learning the API. Post your `MCVE` of your attempt to use the filter. Start by downloading the proper demo code from the tutorial, that shows the basics of how filtering works. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer is more about how to read exception messages, but I think you and others will find it useful.

`ArrarIndexOutOfBound` exceptions are useful because the exception message tell us the index that was used and exactly which line of code caused the error. In the exception posted, we see:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
 at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1195)
```

This tell us two important things:

1. You got the error for trying to remove the **first index** of an EMPTY array. That should be a surprise since your table is probably not empty and if it were, the loop searching for the element to remove should just be skipped without an error.
2. The error was thrown by the Container `remove` method. Without a SSCCE I'm left to speculate that `HireTable` is a `JTable` (which extends Container). Calling the inherited remove method on JTable doesn't make any sense, because the table does not "contain" rows the way, for example, a `JPanel` can contain a number of buttons.

To remove a row, we need to use a TableModel. The `DefaultTableMode` contains a [removeRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow%28int%29) method. Something like this can work:

```
  ((DefaultTableModel)hireTable.getModel()).removeRow(row);
```